# Ошибка BufferOverflowException при передаче файла

Tags: java, файлы, сокет

Вопрос указан в заголовке. Передаю файл частями в канал, появляется ->  `BufferOverflowException` (я понимаю что это исключение появляется при переполнении буфера).
Так же удавалось полностью передать файл размером 50 байт (txt).
Видео, картинки передать не получаеться.
Исключения появляется по разному, нет точной границы успешно передаваемых байт.
Буфер считывает по позициям, позиция соответствует размеру буфера, ничего переполняться не должно.

---

**Дополнение:**

Ещё одно небольшое примечание. Если перед `buffer.flip();` вывести на экран `positionRead -> System.out.println("positionRead " + positionRead);` байты будут записываться в канал (Динамически, как и говорилось выше с появлением исключения). Но если вывод строки убрать - **сразу** без успешно переданных байт получаю `BufferOverflowException`.
Я не знаю в чем причина, но возможно эта информация будет полезна.

Для лучшего понимания картины сделал 4 скрина.

**С** использованием `System.out.println` - https://ibb.co/geAL4S
передалось 30кб из 327кб. - https://ibb.co/h36yb7

**Без** испольования `System.out.println` - https://ibb.co/mwJ7jS
не передалось ничего - https://ibb.co/mXON3n

Comment: Приведите код где вы пишите в сокет, пожалуйста.

Comment: `ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

            fileChannel.read(buffer, positionRead);
            buffer.flip();
            socketChannel.write(buffer);`

Код подробнее -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112763/transfer-a-file

Comment: добавьте после записи buffer.position(0);

Comment: Здравствуйте, добавил, результат тот же

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в том, что вы постоянно уменьшаете лимит буфера, не возвращая его на capacity буфера. Вы наверное вкурсе, что `flip()` ставит лимит на текущую позицию, а текущую позицию на 0, чтобы писались в channel только записанные в буфер данные. Но после записи вы не возвращаете лимит на capacity буфера, возвращаете только позицию. Так вы сжимаете рабочую часть буфера постоянно с каждым вызовом этого метода, не подозревая этого.

Советую вам заменить `buffer.position(0);` в конце на `buffer.clear();` Данный метод присваивает позиции буфера 0, а также присваивает лимиту буфера его вместимость (capacity).

Comment: Заменил, файл до конца не передаётся, теперь появляется -> `IllegalArgumentException: newPosition < 0: (10256 < 0) или `IllegalArgumentException: newPosition > limit: (10256 > 10256)` а иногда `HeapByteBuffer`

Comment: @Akalit так вы сами указываете position, дайте код, что такое readOperation, например, чтобы я мог понять, как у вас получается неверная позиция

Comment: Весь код вы можете посмотреть перейдя по этой ссылке -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112763/transfer-a-file

Comment: @Akalit с первого взгляда на этот код, не заметил у вас проверки на возврат -1 из Future (когда операция завершена, возвращает -1), это может приводить в чтению одного и того же места несколько раз (может это можно делать, тут уже не помню, давно с чистой джавой для неткода не работал). Приду домой еще гляну, можете пока попробовать останавливать метод, если -1.

Comment: Закрытие операции при возвращении -1 ?, скорее всего вы не туда смотрите. Проблемная часть кода находится в условии -> `if (key.isWritable())` там берёться макс размер файла и объектом `Future` возвращает значение, и когда оно достигнит на 1 байт больше чем размер файла - выходит из цыкла